# Create your own ios hooks

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5

I was wondering if any one knows how to create you own hooks in your app.

for example i got an sms with a custom url like `myapp://location?id=1`

and when you click on it it opens `myapp` and shows me what `location?id=1` is

Comment: Look into [URL schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50)

Comment: Check this: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "hook" is within your AppDelegate.

Implement the following method...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    NSString* tUrlString = url.absoluteString;
    // ... analyse tUrlString
    // ... do something
    return YES;
}
```

Furthermore you have to register your app for reacting to the "myapp://" URL scheme (if not already done). This can be done in the "URL Types" within the "Info" section of your app's target.